# Beamer Presentation - non devided subbar issue

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I want to create the following beamer presentation but unfortunately, I couldn't. I don't know which package I need to use to fix this. I am using **pdfpages** package.

**Here's my code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[LLLLLLLL] 
{LLLLLLLL}

\author[]{XX}

\institute{YY \ UU}

\date[]{HHHHH}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

**The desired output is as shown in the picture.**

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: @samcarter I have applied your code, the result of the centred title was correct but unfortunately, page numbering doesn't appear.

Comment: Is your beamer version up-to-date? The page number template I use was added maybe a year ago. If your beamer version is older it won't work.

Comment: @samcarter In fact, I am using Overleaf. )

Comment: Overleaf uses a pretty old latex version. Can you try to add `\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=white}`?

Comment: @samcarter Unfortunately, the same.

Comment: I'll add a second solution for such outdated systems .... arrrrrg, why did I add this handy template if I can't use it?

Comment: @samcarter Thanks a lot. It works very well. ))

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a package to fix this, just a different definition of the footline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[LLLLLLLL] 
{LLLLLLLL}

\author[]{XX}

\institute{YY \ UU}

\date[]{HHHHH}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfil
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** for seriously outdated tex distributions like the one used by overleaf

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
\mode<presentation> {
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[LLLLLLLL] 
{LLLLLLLL}

\author[]{XX}

\institute{YY \ UU}

\date[]{HHHHH}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \hfil
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \hfill
    \makebox[0pt][r]{\insertframenumber\,/\,\inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```